# How to find out what is being modified by an Update query in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of users with 3 fields, UserID, State, and IsLocked.
I'm going to update all users State to 3 and IsLocked to `true`, Before issuing the update query I ran the following two queries:

```
> db.Users.find({isLocked:{$ne:true}})
> db.Users.find({State:{$ne:3}})
```

They both return nothing, so I assume all users have their `isLocked` set to `true` and their `State` are set to 3.
After that I ran the update query:

```
> db.Users.update({},{$set:{State:3,isLocked:true}},{ multi: true })
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 43206, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 3 })
```

I'm very confused about the number of `nModified`.
I expect it to be 0 because all documents already have their `State` set to 3 and `isLocked` to `true`.
Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only get counts in case of updates affecting multiple documents i.e `multi:true`. For single document update you can use `findOneAndUpdate` with `returnNewDocument:true` to return the updated document.

So it looks like you've documents where either State or isLocked fields are missing.

For example

Try

```
db.Users.find({isLocked:{$exists:false}})
db.Users.find({State:{$exists:false}})
```

which should return 3 documents.

Include the check to only update fields where isLocked **and** state both are present.

```
db.Users.update({isLocked:{$exists:true}, State:{$exists:true}},{$set:{State:3,isLocked:true}},{ multi: true })
```

Include the check to only update fields where isLocked **or** state is present.

```
db.Users.update({$or:[{isLocked:{$exists:true}}, {State:{$exists:true}}]},{$set:{State:3,isLocked:true}},{ multi: true })
```